# global variable not working inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, closures, global

```
var count = 0; 
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) { 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    assert( i == count++, "Check the value of i." ); 
  }, i * 200); 
}
```

Why doesnt this work(`i` comes equal to 4 rather than equal to count every time)? `count, var` are created in a global scope so why would they not be available inside the function?

(I would like an explanation as to why this doesn't work, I found a way to get it to work by wrapping it in another function,  just wanting to understand)

Comment: That works just as expected -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrP7Z/), but the value of `i` changes, as you would expect it to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this; Value of i will be 4 inside each setTime out as for loop already finished and value of

Anonymous function will preserve variable inside it by creating new context.

```
var count = 0; 
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) { 
  (function(i){
     setTimeout(function(){ 
            assert( i == count++, "Check the value of i." ); 
      }, i * 200);
  })(i); 
}
```